# Log-on Money Bug

Tags: prison-architect

I have just recently noticed a weird bug. Whenever I disable a mod, when I hit 'Play', it gives me $24,500 for a Grant Completion. Every time. It's definitely a bug, because I currently running 3 Grants, & you can't go higher than that. Unlike some people, who would sit there for hours getting free money, I would like to play a legit game.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a fix for your bug, but if you're worried about "cheating" you can freely edit the amount of money you have in the save file (under "Finances") to remove the extra amount

Comment: @Landric Thanks! I already did that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the grant that gets completed is 'Remove supply of weapons & tools'. At least that's what I've observed before in my saves. There's not much you can do about it. The manual completion of the grant would require a 'shakedown', so you could load the game, get the grant completion, perform the shakedown and... your consciousness is safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible fix for the bug. in the save file if you can find the grants you could un research everything and re research it possibly fixing your bug. Another Idea is too just wait for all the grants to finish 
then save your game.